# Isomorphic to which of the following?

Tags: group-isomorphism

Here's a question that I came across in my textbook. It says:

> Decide whether the following group is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z_4},+)$ or K, where K is the Klein $4$-group.

I am given the following set:

$$\{Id,(12),(34),(12)(34)\}$$

I know that, as a function, this comes out to be $f(x) = x_1+x_2-x_3-x_4$. I also know that if that, in general, a group G is a group of order 4, then it is isomorphic to either $(\mathbb{Z_4},+)$ or K. So how do I determine whether my given set is isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z_4},+)$ or K? I believe that I am suppose to find an element such that when I raise it to the $4^{th}$ power, I get my identity matrix, which is Id. That's as far as I can go with this one.

Comment: Hint: What are the orders of your elements, and what are the orders of the elements in $\mathbb{Z}_4$ and K?

Comment: $o(Id) = 1$, $o((12)) = 2$, $o((34)) = 2$. Like that?

Comment: Ya. Isomorphisms preserve orders, so if, say, you find that none of the elements in that set have order 4, then it can't be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_4$

Comment: Ah I see. Well in that case, what's the order of the last element of my set? I don't believe it is 2...

Comment: The square is somewhere in that set. If not the identity, does it make more sense for $((12)(34))^2$ to be $(12)$ or $(34)$?

Comment: By drawing out a cyclic table, it turns out that $o((12)(34)) = 2$, so since none of the orders of the elements are 4, then my set is isomorphic to $K$.

Comment: @T.Gunn In regards to your question, no it doesn't make sense. It's just that I had to draw out the cyclic table for my function, but it turns out to have order $2$.

Comment: Yes it makes just as much sense for $((12)(34))^2$ to be $(12)$ as it does $(34)$. Since it can't be both, it must be neither, that is, it must be the identity. In the future, note that disjoint cycles commute, so $(12)(34)(12)(34) = (12)(12)(34)(34) = \iota^2 = \iota$.

Comment: Ah disjoint transpositions; I totally forgot they can commute. I will keep that in mind @T.Gunn.

Comment: *Disjoint* transpositions. It is an important distinction: $(12)(23) \ne (23)(12)$.

Comment: Ah yes, I will edit my previous comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once we have established that our set $S=\{\operatorname{id}, (12),(34),(12)(34)\}$ is indeed a group, why don't we just prove your general statement: a group of order 4 is either isomorphic to $(\mathbb{Z}_4,+)$ or $K$?

For the first, we need to check if $S$ is closed under composition and the inclusion of inverses. We consider the action of its elements on the set $\{1,2,3,4\}$ to simplify the compositions.

For the second, we compare their cyclic- and multiplication tables, in order to construct a group isomorphism $a:S \to(\mathbb{Z}_4,+)$ or $b: S\to K$.